# CodenameOne: Bug in Double.parseDouble on iOS

Tags: codenameone

The following code :

```
String test1 = "1.000000108001807564";
String test2 = "1.0000001080018075648";
System.out.println(test1 + " -> " + Double.parseDouble(test1));
System.out.println(test2 + " -> " + Double.parseDouble(test2));
```

works correctly in the simulator and on Android:

```
1.000000108001807564 -> 1.0000001080018075
1.0000001080018075648 -> 1.0000001080018075
```

But fails on iOS:

```
1.000000108001807564 -> 1.0
1.0000001080018075648 -> -1.183888
```

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3250